# How to select specific number of colors to show in color bar from a big list ? - Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I plotted some data which has 70 classes, so when I built the color bar it's very difficult to distinguish between each legend as shown below:

[image]

The code that I'm using is:

```
formation_colors = # 70 colors
formation_labels = # 70 labels
data = # the section of the entire dataset which only has 13  labels


data = data.sort_values(by='DEPTH_MD')
ztop=data.DEPTH_MD.min(); zbot=data.DEPTH_MD.max() 

cmap_formations = colors.ListedColormap(formation_colors[0:len(formation_colors)], 'indexed')
cluster_f = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(data['Formations'].values,1), 100, 1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
im_f = ax.imshow(cluster_f, interpolation='none', aspect='auto', cmap = cmap_formations, vmin=0, vmax=69)   
ax.set_xlabel('FORMATION')
ax.set_xticklabels(['']);

divider_f = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax_f = divider_f.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad=0.05)
cbar_f = plt.colorbar(im_f, cax = cax_f,)

cbar_f.set_ticks(range(0,len(formation_labels))); cbar_f.set_ticklabels(formation_labels)
```

So far, if I just change:

```
   1. cmap_formations = colors.ListedColormap(formation_colors[0:len(formation_colors)], 'indexed') 
   2. cbar_f.set_ticks(range(0,len(formation_labels))); cbar_f.set_ticklabels(formation_labels)
```

to:

```
cmap_formations = colors.ListedColormap(formation_colors[0:len(data['FORMATION'].unique())], 'indexed') 

cbar_f.set_ticks(range(0,len(data['FORMATION'].unique()))); cbar_f.set_ticklabels(data['FORMATION'].unique())
```

I get, the corresponding colors in the cbar, however the plot is no longer correct  and also the legends are out of square

[image]

Thank you so much if you have any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not explicitly mentioned in the question, I suppose `data['FORMATION']` contains indices from `0` till `69` into the lists of `formation_colors` and `formation_labels`

The main problem is that `data['FORMATION']` needs to be renumbered to be new indices (with numbers `0` till `12`) into the new list of unique colors.  `np.unique(..., return_inverse=True)` returns both the list of unique numbers, and the renumbering for the values.

To be able to reindex the list of colors and of labels, it helps to convert them to numpy arrays.

To make the code easier to debug, the following test uses a simple relation between the list of colors and the list of labels.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

formation_colors = np.random.choice(list(colors.CSS4_COLORS), 70, replace=False)  # 70 random color names
formation_labels = ['lbl_' + c for c in formation_colors]  # 70 labels
formation_colors = np.asarray(formation_colors)
formation_labels = np.asarray(formation_labels)

f = np.random.randint(0, 70, 13)
d = np.sort(np.random.randint(0, 5300, 13))
data = pd.DataFrame({'FORMATION': np.repeat(f, np.diff(np.append(0, d))),
                     'DEPTH_MD': np.arange(d[-1])})
data = data.sort_values(by='DEPTH_MD')

ztop = data['DEPTH_MD'].min()
zbot = data['DEPTH_MD'].max()

unique_values, formation_new_values = np.unique(data['FORMATION'], return_inverse=True)
cmap_formations = colors.ListedColormap(formation_colors[unique_values], 'indexed')
cluster_f = formation_new_values.reshape(-1, 1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
im_f = ax.imshow(cluster_f, extent=[0, 1, zbot, ztop],
                 interpolation='none', aspect='auto', cmap=cmap_formations, vmin=0, vmax=len(unique_values)-1)
ax.set_xlabel('FORMATION')
ax.set_xticks([])

divider_f = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax_f = divider_f.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad=0.05)
cbar_f = plt.colorbar(im_f, cax=cax_f)

cbar_f.set_ticks(np.linspace(0, len(unique_values)-1, 2*len(unique_values)+1)[1::2])
cbar_f.set_ticklabels(formation_labels[unique_values])

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, right=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Here is a comparison plot:

[image: example plot]

Comment: Brillant! Thank you @JohanC.